# Lower bound for a linear form with integers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Let $\|x\|$ denotes the distance between $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and the nearest integer to $x$.

It's an easy application of Dirichlet pigeonhole principle to prove that for any $N\geq 2$ there exist integers $m,n$ such that $|m|,|n|\leq N$, $(m,n)\ne(0,0)$ and 
$$\|m\sqrt2+n\sqrt3\|<\frac{1}{N^2}.$$

I'm interested in the lower bound of $\|m\sqrt2+n\sqrt3\|$. For example, is it true that for some (or any?) $\varepsilon>0$ and $c=c(\varepsilon)>0$ we have
$$\|m\sqrt2+n\sqrt3\|>\frac{c}{N^{2+\varepsilon}}$$
for all $|m|,|n|\leq N$, $(m,n)\ne(0,0)$?

I have a feeling it's something known (or have been studied) in number theory. If so, a nice reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $(m\sqrt2+n\sqrt3)(m\sqrt2-n\sqrt3)=2m^2-3n^2$ is a nonzero integer, hence, at least $1$ in absolute value, and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

By [Roth's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem), since $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ is algebraic, there are only finitely many $\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $$\left|\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}- \frac{m}{n} \right| < \frac{1}{n^{2+ \epsilon}}.$$  Thus, there is a $c= c(\epsilon)$ such that $$\left|\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}- \frac{m}{n} \right| > \frac{c}{n^{2+ \epsilon}}$$ for all $m$ and $n$.  This implies your statement.

Comment: Roth's Theorem is really overkill when dealing with numbers of degree 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Yes, I agree.  But it shows the OP that the same holds for any two algebraic numbers..

Comment: Well, any two algebraic irrationals.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Correct, it is not true for any two rational numbers.

Comment: It in fact implies that $|n\sqrt2-m\sqrt3|>\frac{c\sqrt3}{N^{1+\epsilon}}$, but how is it related to $\|n\sqrt2+m\sqrt3\|$? I think we need something like $|n\sqrt2-m\sqrt3-k|$ ($m,n,k\in\mathbb{Z}$) instead of $|n\sqrt2-m\sqrt3|$.